# htaccess существующий файл

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите, пожалуйста, с htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#Склейка www.домен.ру с домен.ру
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
#редирект на поддомен
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru
RewriteRule my/(.*)$ http://my.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
#при запросе из поддомена
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.site.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В папке site.ru/my/action/ лежат php-обработчики. Нужно обращаться к ним по ссылке вида my.site.ru/action/***имя_обработчика***. Либо не обязательно из поддомена, но чтобы можно было обращаться, т.к. сейчас такой путь ссылается на индексный файл.

Comment: @Regent, очень глубоко. это в просторечии (и для людей, от темы далёких) вполне допустимо, но никак не на ресурсе, претендующем на объективность и авторитетность. достаточно кратко и «полтикорректно», на мой взгляд, написано [на сайте, где собираются действительно «специалисты в данном вопросе»](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/linux/info)